# js function not able to select content of html input box

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Consider the following excerpt from an html-code:

```
<td>Field X: <br/><input type="text" id="field_x" value=""></td>
```

I want to get the content of the InputField with id "field_x". To this end I have written the following javascript function:

```
function get_content(){
    var content = document.querySelector("field_x").value;
    return content;
}
```

However, for some reason the line

```
var content = document.querySelector("field_x").value;
```

within the function does not work and results in the following error message:

> "Cannot read property 'value' of null"

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Typo, you forgot the `#` in `document.querySelector("field_x").value`. You should learn to do some basic debugging with the browser's console.

Comment: Use `document.querySelector("#field_x").value` or simply `document.getElementById("field_x").value`

Answer (score 2):

Correct syntax would be:

```
var content = document.querySelector("#field_x").value;
```

or

```
var content = document.getElementById("field_x").value;
```

Comment: remove # from id selector

Comment: @Mahi Thanks. That's what I get for copy and pasting the first line to the second...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `#` sign in your selector.